# docker-compose is not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper, boot2docker

When I am trying to test a zookeeper cluster using docker-compose, the console shows nothing.

This is my command:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=zk_test docker-compose up
```

No response of `docker-compose` command [image: screenshot]

My questions are:

1. I only installed docker-machine and docker-compose. The command is there, but do I need to install docker-compose additionally?
2. Should docker-compose be installed inside docker machine or in host machin? If the latter, how does docker-compose manage Docker containers?  Because they are running inside of the Docker machine.

What I think is weird, is that when I input 'docker-compose' in the host terminal, it can be recognized by the OS ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr5lD.png)).

My environment:

- OS: Mac
- Docker container: docker-machine (boot2docker)

Comment: I am sure that docker-compose and docker-machine are both to be installed within the host machine, you do not have to install anything twice, refer : https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/

Comment: Installing docker doesn't mean that you've installed docker-compose. It has as prerequisites that you've already installed the docker engine which you've already done.

Comment: You don't need to install docker-composer or docker inside a container unless you want to launch services/containers from a started docker. If you want to do that, you should have to include docker and docker-compose installation in Dockerfile, and after that share /var/run/docker.sock mounting volume in the same placement for docker.

Comment: How have you installed docker-compose? If you've downloaded a not recent version you've to install docker toolbox

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I get all necessary packages on my Mac OS machine.

Install homebrew:

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Then brew cask install docker

`brew cask install docker`

Open Docker through `Applications` or:

`open /Applications/Docker.app`

You should now how docker-compose, docker and docker-engine.

Answer (score 0):

First up, docker and docker compose *should* be installed in the machine that you want to run the containers on, but it is still possible to remotely control the engine, for example by utilizing a TCP socket.

Secondly, in your case, the container probably crashed / exited. To verify this, run `docker-compose ps -a` (compose V1), `docker compose ps -a` (compose V2) or `docker ps -a` (shows all containers, even services that aren't defined in the local compose file).
Notice the `-a` (= `all`) which makes it display stopped (and therefore failed) containers as well. Per default, only running containers are shown.